# Двумерный String массив

Tags: java

Вопрос заключается в следующем. У меня есть 2 метода. В каждом из методов, в цикле, переменным (`notInitialised` и `initialised`) присваиваются `string` значения. Необходимо, полученные эти значения, сохранить в двумерный массив - `String [notInitialised][initialised]`. Как правильно его реализовать?

```
public void notInitialised(){
...
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        ...
        notInitialised = matcherNotInitialised.group();
    }
    ...
}

public void initialised(){
...
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        ...
        initialised = matcherInitialised.group();
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не совсем понятно куда сохранять.

Можно так:

```
String[][] values = new String[2][5];
int initializedIndex = 0;
int nonInitializedIndex = 0;
public void notInitialised(){
...
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        ...
        notInitialised = matcherNotInitialised.group();
        values[0][nonInitializedIndex++] = nonInitialized;
    }
    ...
}

public void initialised(){
...
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        ...
        initialised = matcherInitialised.group();
        values[1][initializedIndex++] = initialized;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: я думаю, если это реализовать таким способом, то нужно сохранять не 2 разные переменный, а одну с булевским состоянием, типа 1 - initialised, 0 - notInitialised. А если "не таким" способом, но лучше пользоваться коллекцией, которая будет хранить эти объекты

Comment: ну есть какой-то твой объект - OBJ, который содержит переменную Initialised, ты создаешь, например, ArrayList<OBJ>() list = new ArrayList();, который будет хранить все твои объекты и перебирая, который, ты сможешь выставить значения для Initialised.
Чет мне кажется, я усложняю объяснения, но это ООП подход, тут нечего странного вроде бы нету